# 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my code,and it appears a problem like the topic. i am a primary learner and i don't know where is the problem. could u help me fix the code and tell me which part of knowledge i need to review. thanks in advance.

```
x = int(raw_input("enter the value of x:"))
y = int(raw_input("enter the value of y:"))
i = 0
j = 0
array=[x*y]
for i in range(x):
    array.append([0 for j in range(y)])
for i in range(x-1):
for j in range(y-1):
    array[i][j]=i * j
print array
```

Comment: `array=[x*y]`seems wrong.

Comment: Your syntax is so wrong. First of all if you store variables `i=0, j=0` so why you use them in `for` loop? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your code "works" (runs without errors) if I change `array=[x*y]` to just `array = []`, and indent the `for j in range()` line properly. I'm not sure if the result is what you intended though, so maybe you should try to explain what your code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @Marius thank you! i find it works! When i first start to create a array, i thought i need give it enough space, with i*j elements. so i did it. thank you!

Comment: @howaboutNO it looks like OP is used to declaring variables, which is of course not needed in python

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a list of mixed types, integers and lists, and then trying to access the integer value as if it was a list.

Let's use a simple example:

```
x = 2
y = 3
i = 0
j = 0
array = [x*y]
```

Now, let's look at what `array` currently contains:

```
array
>> 6
```

Now we run your first for loop:

```
for i in range(x):
    array.append([0 for j in range(y)])
```

And let's check the new value of `array`:

```
array
>> [6, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

So now we see that the first element of `array` is an integer. The remaining elements are all lists with three elements.

The error occurs in the first pass through your nested for loops. In the first pass, i and j are both zero.

```
array[0][0] = 0*0
>> TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Since `array[0]` is an integer, you can't use the second `[0]`. There is nothing there to get. So, like Ashalynd said, the `array = x*y` seems to be the problem.

Depending on what you really want to do, there could be many solutions. Let's assume you want the first element of your list to be a list of length y, with each value equal to `x*y`. Then replace `array = [x*y]` with:

```
array = [x*y for i in range(y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is so wrong. First of all if you store variables `i=0, j=0` so why you use them in `for` loop? It doesn't make any sense.

Second, just debug it, put `print (array)` after the list.

if x=5 and y=5 ;

> [25, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

This is your array, and this line;

```
array[i][j]=i * j
```

Throwing error? Why? Because;

```
j=0
i=0
array[i]=25
array[i][j] = 2
```

So that's why you got error.Integers, which is `2` here, doesn't support item assignment. Try to fix your syntax.

Comment: Your explanation of item assignment is confusing. It sounds like you're saying that the `2` in `array[i][j] = 2` doesn't support item assignment, which is not the case.

Comment: yep, i agree, my syntax is so wrong. i thought i should give i and j values to initialize them. Actually the expression : array.append([0 for j in range(y)]) is what i learn from the correct answer, i don't know why it works. could u explain it? thank you.

Comment: @johnwayyang No, you don't have to do that, Please check some basic tutorials in web about Python

Comment: @johnwayyang np mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspect your array.

array[2*3] will result in [6].

array.append([0 for j in range(3)]) will then result in [6,[0,0,0]], your first element is not an array.

There is in indent error with your for loops.

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
array2=[]
for i in range(2):
   array2.append([0 for j in range(3)])
```